# Symfony2 empty string, no translation in template

Tags: symfony

I can't understand why I've got empty text instead of translation in `{{'enter.data.register'|trans}}`

I've added files with translations into my bundle. And when I check it with `translation:debug` I've got correct info:

```
| State(s) | Id                  | Message Preview (ru)                 | Fallback Message Preview (en) |
+----------+---------------------+--------------------------------------+-------------------------------+
|          | enter.data.register | Для регистрации заполните форму      | Enter your data to register
```

With profiler I can see that `_locale` in request was set. Should I do something else for translation to start work?

Comment: Are you viewing this in the production environment? Have you cleared the prod cache? `php app/console cache:clear --env=prod`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it's a TYPO because twig needs a required space just after the start and before the end of the brackets `{{ '...' }}`

But if it's not the case and considering that I don't know where you use the message and the type of the message (some `translations` files have a predefined name like `validators` and `messages`), have you tried to add a translation domain like this:

`{{ 'enter.data.register'|trans({}, 'YourDomainBundle') }}`

or like this if you are using a custom [Message Domain](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/translation/introduction.html#using-message-domains) file name:

`{{ 'enter.data.register'|trans({}, 'exampledomain') }}`

Comment: Glad to be helpful but the error was a TYPO or DOMAIN NAME?

Comment: I should enter message domain